# Why is Axios call in useEffect returning data only once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering why is data from api call with axios returned only once, and every other time it's an empty array which is predefined. Here's the code:

```
let { id } = useParams();
var [activity, setActivity] = useState([]);
var [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {

    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/auth/admin", {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'x-access-token': AuthHeader()['x-access-token']
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.data.unauthorized) {
            AuthService.logout();
        }
    });

    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/auth/get_activity/${id}`).then((response) => {
        setActivity(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(activity);
    });


}, [id]);
```

Now when user clicks on the link on the other page, `history.push(/user-activity/${value._id}` gets him to this page and the id which is useParams is used for axios.get to collect data and display it, but it only happens when I add or remove the id in useEffect condition and refresh the page.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: your question  is really unclear please edit it and explain more and tell us these thing (what is the problem, what is the expectation, what is the output)

Comment: Well I thought I explained but here's again:
Each time page is visited, activity should be set response.data from axios get method as you can see in the question. But it's always empty array as it's defined in the begingin. There is no data from response. When I use the call in Postman, it works fine but in app it doesn't.

Comment: You log an activity right after you set it, setting the state is async action and must be handled properly

Comment: Can you please explain your answer better, I removed console.log and it's still the same problem, no data from api call.

Comment: Also, does your api call depend on  this `axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/auth/admin")`?

Comment: No, it does not, it's just a security check.

Comment: Then from the code you shared it all looks okay, so the problem could be with axios not returning data you want (you can try to log response), or some other problem outside the piece of code you shared

Answer (score 0):

useEffect() runs on every subsequent re-render or update. Now we can skip it if we pass the second parameter (which is an array that contains a list of state variables to watch for). You already have passed it, the `[id]` but now react will only re-run the side effect if one of the items in this array changes.

Are your state variables being updated/changed? Because if it isn't then it will not be triggered, because it considers it same and not unique.

Comment: Well even if I don't add id in the useEffect, it's still the same thing, it returns an empty response. And I need it to run on every re-render.

Comment: then remove the second parameter, do not pass it and it will re render every time. But be sure if you really need it like that.

Comment: As I already mentioned, even if it's removed, on each re-render it returns an empty array.

Comment: I mean don't pass anything at all. Like are you doing this `[]` or not passing this second argument at all, thats what I meant, like this

`useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Component mounted')
})`

Comment: I just add [] and that's it. When I don't add anything, it executes endlessly and then it returns the data - endlessly.

Comment: @WahabShah it makes no sense, if data is set on first render and "id" is not changing the useEffect is not triggered and the data is not reset. removing [] will cause infinite loop

Comment: Well I'll check the whole code, back-end and front-end. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Here is the thing, in .then() before I assign response.data to the activity, I console log it and the data is there, but when I console.log() activity after it's set, it's still an empty array.

Comment: yeah that's true it will go into endless loop. there is some issue while setting the setActivity(). Try passing a default value in activity array and console.log the activity if that is coming (it would come and keep on coming the same).  Actually data updates in the next render its because of async nature and closure.  Try one more thing. Call another useEffect() below exiting one and console.log the activity there. In the first use effect pass the empty array and in second new useEffect pass the id inside the array as second argument. This will work hopefully just try it for testing confirm